# I have errors trying to catkinize MIDG II package

Tags: ros, gps, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to catkinize a package I found on Github to run my "Microrobotics MIDG II INS/GPS" sensor on ROS.
I used "catkinize" and follwed the instructions to edit my `CMakeList` and package files.

After finishing all steps I am getting this error messge and I couldn't find any help to fix it.

```
...
midgPacket.cpp:(.text+0xa15): undefined reference to `ros::console::setLogLocationLevel(ros::console::LogLocation*, ros::console::levels::Level)'
midgPacket.cpp:(.text+0xa1f): undefined reference to `ros::console::checkLogLocationEnabled(ros::console::LogLocation*)'
midgPacket.cpp:(.text+0xa6a): undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, void*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/renawi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/midg/Midg] Error 1
make[1]: *** [midg/CMakeFiles/Midg.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

My CMakeList file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(midg)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp geometry_msgs std_msgs sensor_msgs message_generation)
include_directories(include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
add_message_files(
  DIRECTORY msg
  FILES
  IMU.msg
)
#uncomment if you have defined services
#add_service_files(
#  FILES
#  IMU.srv
#)

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/Midg_II.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Midg)

#target_link_libraries(${midg}-test ${midg})
#add_executable(midg midg/midg.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})

#rosbuild_find_ros_package(mst_common)
#INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${mst_common_PACKAGE_PATH}/include)

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs std_msgs)

#generate_messages()
# catkin_package parameters: 
#http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html

#catkin-package
# TODO: fill in what other packages will need to use this package
catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs std_msgs message_runtime roscpp sensor_msgs)

#install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#  )
   # PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE

add_executable(Midg src/Midg_II.cpp src/drivers/midgPacket.cpp)
add_dependencies(Midg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

There are many of the "undefined reference to..." messages showing up before the error message

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246465/i-have-errors-trying-to-catkinize-midg-ii-package/) by [AbdRenawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28149/abdrenawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-26**:
Please use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) to format things like console text, contents of `CMakeLists.txt`, compiler errors and code snippets.

Please use the *edit* button/link (below your question) to fix the formatting.

Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-26**:
Also: when posting `CMakeLists.txt` (thanks for that btw, always a good idea when posting compiler and/or linker errors), please remove all the boilerplate comments from them (lines starting with `#`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved, I created a new driver for MIDG II INS/GPS sensor that works on any platform that supports ROS.
available at: https://github.com/AbdRenawi/MIDG-II-INS-GPS-driver

---

Originally posted by [AbdRenawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28149/abdrenawi/) with karma: 31 on 2017-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0